# Autofill to and Adjacent Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and I can't quite find the answer im looking for. The rest of my code is working, but when it comes to autofilling, I can't seem to get it. I have a cell, and I want to autofill just to the cell below. I know its a very basic question, but any help is appriciated! Here's my code:

Selection.AutoFill Destination:= Range(Cells.ActiveCell.Offset(1,0), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault

Comment: Forgot to mention that I keep getting the "Run Time 1004" error

Answer (score 1):

You could use Resize

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Resize(2, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: Any answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

.AutoFill is overrated, Both .FillDown/.FillRight and .DataSeries are usually better methods and filling everything at once with relative content is always an option for formulas or constants.

```
Selection.filldown       'ctrl+D is faster
'or,
Selection.cells(1).resize(2, 1).filldown

...

Selection.cells(1).resize(2, 1) = Selection.cells(1).formula

...

Selection.cells(1).resize(2, 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1

...

'only if you're feeling lucky
selection.flashfill
```

You haven't provided anywhere near enough information to offer a definitive answer but all of the above are viable alternatives to the guessing game called .AutoFill with a Type:=xlFillDefault argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try out these tests. The code for column A answers your original question.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub AutofillTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim aRng1 As Range, aRng2 As Range

    'Autofill beginnining with only one cell as a "seed"
    ws.Range("a:d").Clear
    Set aRng1 = ws.Range("a1:a1")
    aRng1 = 1 'The "seed" cell
    Set aRng2 = aRng1.Offset(1, 0)
    aRng1.AutoFill Destination:=Range(aRng1, aRng2), Type:=xlFillSeries

    'More fun tests
    ws.Range("b1:b1") = 1
    ws.Range("c1:c1") = 1
    ws.Range("d1:d1") = CDate("5/1/2018")
    ws.Range("b1:b1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("b1:b5"), Type:=xlFillSeries 'List of numbers
    ws.Range("c1:c1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("c1:c5"), Type:=xlFillDefault 'Copy of one number
    ws.Range("d1:d1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("d1:d5"), Type:=xlFillDefault 'List of dates
End Sub
```

Comment: It's an answer. It solves the problem as well as teaches a little more.